# How can i use nested query in the following two queries

Tags: mysql

My first query is :

```
SELECT SUM(expenses.amount) as project_expenses 
FROM expenses 
WHERE project_id=$project_id
```

My second query is :

```
    SELECT customer_deal.*,recipt_no_agency.*,expense_type.exp_head,project.name,
    expenses.type_id ,SUM(recipt_no_agency.payment) as pay 
    FROM customer_deal 
    LEFT JOIN project ON customer_deal.project_id=project.project_id 
    LEFT JOIN recipt_no_agency ON recipt_no_agency.recipt_id=customer_deal.id     
    LEFT JOIN expenses ON expenses.project_id=customer_deal.id 
    LEFT JOIN expense_type ON expenses.type_id=customer_deal.id 
    WHERE project.project_id=$project_id
```

Please help.

Comment: explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: want to nest the two queries such that it works properly as they working separetly

Comment: @SafdarPathan it's still unclear what you're trying to achieve. Could you please share your tables' structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this data?